# NoReverseMatch at /basket/ Reverse for 'one_phone' not found. 'one_phone' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

Учусь делать корзину и возникла проблема. Есть товар и корзина. Когда дело доходит до того, когда нужно выбрать товар и добавить его в корзину, то появляется вот такая ошибка:

```
NoReverseMatch at /basket/
Reverse for 'one_phone' not found. 'one_phone' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Не понимаю, где я ошибся. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Вот **view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404

from mobile.models import Product
from .basket import Basket
from .forms import BasketAddProductForm

from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST


@require_POST
def basket_add(request, one_phone):

    basket = Basket(request)
    product_obj = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=one_phone)
    form = BasketAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        basket_info = form.cleaned_data
        basket.add(product_obj, count_product=basket_info['count_prod'], update_count=basket_info['update'])
    return redirect('list_basket_prod')

def basket_remove(request, one_phone):
    basket = Basket(request)
    product_obj = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=one_phone)
    basket.remove(product_obj)
    return redirect('list_basket_prod')

def basket_info(request):
    basket = Basket(request)
    return render(request, 'basket/detail.html', {'basket': basket})

def basket_clear(request):
    basket = Basket(request)
    basket.clear()
    return redirect('phone_list')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [

    path('', basket_info, name='list_basket_prod'),

    path('add/<int:one_phone>/', basket_add, name='add_basket_prod'),
    path('remove/<int:one_phone>', basket_remove, name='remove_basket_prod'),
    path('clear/', basket_clear, name='clear_basket_prod'),

]
```

вот **detail.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
    Корзина
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="container">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Смартфон</th>
                    <th scope="col">Изображение</th>
                    <th scope="col">Количество</th>
                    <th scope="col">Цена за шт.</th>
                    <th scope="col">Общая цена</th>
                    <th scope="col">Удаление</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for item in basket %}
                {% with product_obj=item.product %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="{% url 'one_phone' product_obj.pk %}"></a>
                            {{ product_obj.name }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {% if product_obj.photo %}
                                <img src="{{ product_obj.photo.url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                            {% else %}
                                <img src="{% static 'image/icon.jpg' %}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                            {% endif %}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ item.count_prod }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ item.price_prod }}
                        </td>
                        <td> ₽</td>
                        <td>
                            {{ item.total_price }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="{% url 'remove_basket_prod' product_obj.pk %}">Удалить</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endwith %}
            {% endfor %}
            <tr>
                <td>Всего: </td>
                <td colspan="4"></td>
                <td>{{ basket.get_total_price }}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <div>
        <a href="{% url 'phone_list' %}" class="btn btn-warning">Еще</a>
        <a href="{% url 'clear_basket_prod' %}" class="btn btn-danger">Очистить</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Оформить заказ</a>
    </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**basket.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from mobile.models import Product

class Basket:
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.session = request.session
        basket = self.session.get(settings.BASKET_SESSION_ID)
        if not basket:
            basket = self.session[settings.BASKET_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.basket = basket

    def save(self):
        self.session[settings.BASKET_SESSION_ID] = self.basket
        self.session.modified = True

    def add(self, product, count_product=1, update_count=False):
        prod_pk = str(product.pk)
        if prod_pk not in self.basket:
            self.basket[prod_pk] = {
                'count_prod': 0,
                'price_prod': str(product.price)
            }
        if update_count:
            self.basket[prod_pk]['count_prod'] = count_product
        else:
            self.basket[prod_pk]['count_prod'] += count_product
        self.save()

    def remove(self, product,):
        prod_pk = str(product.pk)
        if prod_pk in self.basket:
            del self.basket[prod_pk]
            self.save()

    def get_total_price(self):
        return sum(float(item['price_prod']) * int(item['count_prod'])for item in self.basket.values())

    def clear(self):
        del self.session[settings.BASKET_SESSION_ID]
        self.session.modified = True

    def __len__(self):
        return sum(int(item['count_prod'])for item in self.basket.values())

    def __iter__(self):
        list_prod_pk = self.basket.keys()
        list_prod_obj = Product.objects.filter(pk__in=list_prod_pk)
        basket = self.basket.copy()
        for prod_obj in list_prod_obj:
            basket[str(prod_obj.pk)]['product'] = prod_obj
            for item in basket.values():
                item['total_price'] = float(item['price_prod']) * int(item['count_prod'])
                yield item
```

Comment: Ну все правильно. У вас нет такого урла

Answer (score 0):

У вас не добавлен URL `basket/` (о чём и написано в ошибке).

Исправить это можно как-то так:

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [

    path('', basket_info, name='list_basket_prod'),

    path('add/<int:one_phone>/', basket_add, name='add_basket_prod'),
    path('remove/<int:one_phone>', basket_remove, name='remove_basket_prod'),
    path('basket/', basket_info, name='basket_info'),  # Добавить
    path('clear/', basket_clear, name='clear_basket_prod'),

]
```